# how to calculate work done in moving a charge, when the path and point charge don't lie on one line?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, work

**Problem:** 
    A charge Q in point O=(0,0) and a test charge q in point A=(4,1) lie in a plane.
How much work W needs to be done to move q to point B=(2,2).
Q always stays at (0,0).
Q=q= 2*10^-4. One unit here equals 1 meter.

[image]

I found two formulas to  calculate the work done. One is with this path integral:

$ W_{AB}$  = W($ r_A,r_B $)=q*  $ \int_{r_A}^{r_B} E*dr $
but here is the one I tried to use:

$ W_{AB}$ = q*Δ U = q*($ \frac  {kQ} {r_A} $  - $ \frac  {kQ} {r_B} $ )

Now here's my problem, what are the distances
$ r_A $and 
$r_B $ that i have to use here?
It would be easy if all the points would be on one line , but here I am not sure what I am supposed to do.

Can I just use: this length 
$r_A $=$ | \vec {OA} |$ = $ \sqrt 17$ $     
r_B $ = $| \vec {OB} | $ = $\sqrt 8 $.

Or do I have to do something else, like do I maybe need to follow the equipotential lines like this?:

[image]

If so ,then how can I put this into mathematics so i can plug it into one of the equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The electric field due to a stationary charge is a conservative field. The work done taking a test charge, *q*, from A to B is independent of the route by which it goes. 
The red route that you've chosen makes calculations easiest. This is because *no* work is done over CB, as the force is always at right angles to the displacement. The rest I leave to you.

Comment: So if I understood correctly:
I calculated the intersection between the circle throuth (0,0) with r= |OB|
and the line OA to get my point C(24/9, 3/4).




My r_A is now the same as |OA|. And now I know my r_B = |OC| ?
so in case i didn't miscalculate, i got r_A =√17  and  r_B= √(1105/144)


When The work done over CB =0  I think then I only need to calculate:


q* (kQ/√17   -    kQ/ √(1105/144) ) ?


Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Surely $r_B$ is simply $2 \sqrt 2$ ?

Comment: You don't need the co-ordinates of C. Just note that $r_C = r_B = 2 \sqrt 2$.

Comment: ah yeah found the mistake in my calculation, tbh I don't see without computing it why it should be 2√2, would appreciate a quick explanation.

Comment: Pythagoras applied to the point (2, 2).